# wso2 CEP in-built function - isMatch

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing

I am trying to use CEP 3.1.0 with a built in function for regexp matching

```
 from cseEventStream[isMatch('foo\sbar',symbol)]
```

which should match "foo bar" and not "foobar". However, this fails with an error mesage

> mismatched character '\' expecting '''

I have tried escaping with multiple '\'. Also, [isMatch('foo bar',symbol)] does not work. Although, from cseEventStream[symbol contains 'foo\sbar'] is a temporary workaround, the inability to use '\' is a severe limitation in regexp matching.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's looking for the '\' character. What does it say in the isMatch documentation? As it says it is expecting a ' then maybe you have to use '\    ??

Answer (score 0):

It seems an issue with the siddhi compiler when handling "\". I have raised a jira at [1] and attached the patch which solves the issue as well..We'll fix it in next release..

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP-865

Thanks..